# mapd-connector for connecting-to-the-server-and-rendering-the-visualization

Tags: node.js, npm, mapdb

Hi I am beginner for the Mapd database , i started to practicing the CURD Operation in mapd database its working fine, and right now i am started to working on [link](https://www.mapd.com/docs/latest/mapd-core-guide/vegaAtaGlance/#connecting-to-the-server-and-rendering-the-visualization) rendering visualization in the mapd database using the Vega , so i followed the link to the mapd to front-end connector [link1](https://github.com/mapd/mapd-connector) but i tried windows 10 system as well as ubuntu 14 LTS , npm version 5.0.3 and node version v8.1.3  for building "mapd-connector.js" , but unfortunately "mapd-connector.js"  not building , i don't know how to do that , if any one knows how to build "mapd-connector.js" please share the link , Thank you..while building time i am getting this error.

> WARNING in ./~/ws/lib/BufferUtil.js
>   Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' ../build/Release/bufferutil in /home/siftgrid/temp/mapd-connector/node_modules/ws/lib
>    @ ./~/ws/lib/BufferUtil.js 8:19-57

WARNING in ./~/ws/lib/BufferUtil.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' ../build/default/bufferutil in /home/siftgrid/temp/mapd-connector/node_modules/ws/lib
 @ ./~/ws/lib/BufferUtil.js 10:19-57

WARNING in ./~/ws/lib/Validation.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' ../build/Release/validation in /home/siftgrid/temp/mapd-connector/node_modules/ws/lib
 @ ./~/ws/lib/Validation.js 8:19-57

WARNING in ./~/ws/lib/Validation.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' ../build/default/validation in /home/siftgrid/temp/mapd-connector/node_modules/ws/lib
 @ ./~/ws/lib/Validation.js 10:19-57

Comment: Finally i got the solution , in mapd, mapd-connector.js changed to node-connector.js and browser-connector.js

Comment: Eventhough my issue is not solved [link] (https://github.com/mapd/mapd-connector/issues/30) could you anyone tell me how to rendering back-end to front end image rendering in mapd with vega , as per the documentation they are using the Json file not in query based json , so i am searching the correct link for my requirement ,if anyone knows how to do please share the link..Thank you..